# Error: javax.wireless.messaging does not exist

Tags: java

I'm not java developer, but I need to test a code. I installed jdk and i tested Hello Word it worked fine but When i try to javac this another script, I'm gettings this error.

My Code:

```
import javax.wireless.messaging.MessageConnection;
import javax.wireless.messaging.TextMessage;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SMSUtility {

public static void sendMessage(String msisdn, String text)
    throws IOException {

    // Open connection
    MessageConnection con = (MessageConnection)
    Connector.open("sms://+" + msisdn);

    // Create new message
    TextMessage message = (TextMessage)
    con.newMessage(MessageConnection.TEXT_MESSAGE);

    // Set text
    message.setPayloadText(text);

    // Send message
    con.send(message);

    // Close connection
    con.close();

}

}
```

Comment: Nice method, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

`javax.wireless` is not part of the SDK. Read about the [Wireless Messaging API](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/wma/).

Comment: @RafaelPaulaSilva: Yes you have to download it and add it to your build path.

Comment: I need to download it: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/overview/index.html?

Answer (score 0):

javax.messaging is in wma20.jar, but i can't figure out, how to add it to buildpath with ant...